# In dart, how to read a file by line in browser?

Tags: dart

On the server side, there is readline for file operation, which is very convenient for large file process. However, this is not available for the browser side, how could I read a large file line by line on the browser side? OR how could I upload a super large file which can't fit in the RAM?

Answer (score 4):

There is a LineSplitter class that seems to be designed that purpose https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-convert.LineSplitter

you can use it like

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  new HttpClient().getUrl(
      Uri.parse('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/45776/45776-h/45776-h.htm'))
    .then((r) => r.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) => handleResponse(response));
}

void handleResponse(HttpClientResponse response) {
  LineSplitter ls = new LineSplitter();
  ls.bind(UTF8.decoder.bind(response)).listen((e)=> print('=====${e}====='));
}
```

alternative solution using transform like suggested by @lrn

```dart
void main() {
  new HttpClient().getUrl(
      Uri.parse('http://www.gutenberg.org/files/45776/45776-h/45776-h.htm'))
    .then((r) => r.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder)
        .transform(new LineSplitter())
        .listen((e) => print('====${e}===='));
  });
}
```

In the browser I miss something that converts `ProgressEvent`s to a `Stream<String>`.
Maybe someone else knows more.
This seems only be supported with WebSockets but not with HttpRequest.

Comment: You can even use the `transform` method on Stream to allow a more "flow like" writing of the same thing: `response.transform(UTF8.decoder).transform(ls).listen(...)`.

Comment: if you are using import 'dart:io'; doesn't that mean this solution won't run client side?

Comment: I used dart:io for the HttpRequest and yes this doesnt work in the browser. HttpRequest in the browser doesn't support getting the response as stream. You need WebSocket for this which I havent used myself yet. The LineSplitting works with every Stream<String> and also in the browser.